# ExtJS 2 forms, latter one showing results associated with the first one

Tags: forms, extjs, handler

I have a form, which has lists, and a submit button, when an item is chosen from the list another form opens, containing items corresponding to the item chosen from the first form. What I want to do is hide the second for when new item is chosen, update the dropdown of the second form to show items associated with the option chosen from the first form, whenever submit button is clicked. So on click the handler should hide second form, update the list and show the form again. When I do this, I get blank form, and everytime I click submit it adds new (2nd) form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added idCounter, which just added +1 to each div or form, and when hiding and showing, new ones created.